# Error creating OrmLite database on Android 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, ormlite, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm using OrmLite library to work with database in my Android application. It works fine on all versions of Android, but I faced with a trouble on Android 5.1.1 (API 22). I have a class `DBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`. In the onCreate method I create tables for my database

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, final ConnectionSource connectionSource)
{
    try {
        for (Class c : models)
            TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, c);
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.e("error creating DB " + DATABASE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Variable `models` is an array of classes that describing fields of each table.

```
Class[] models = {
    User.class,
    Profile.class,
    Offer.class,
    Partner.class,
    OfferCategory.class,
    PrizeCategory.class,
    ...
```

I found that when table OfferCategory is created there is an exception`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.j256.ormlite.field.DataPersister.getDefaultWidth()' on a null object reference`. Here is my class OfferCategory

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@DatabaseTable(tableName= DbHelper.TABLE_CATEGORY)
public class OfferCategory implements Serializable
{

public static final String FIELD_ID = "_id",
                           FIELD_ORDER = "_order";

public Bundle toBundle()
{
    final Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable(getClass().getName(), this);
    return b;
}

public static final BaseModel fromBundle(final Bundle b, final Class<?> cl)
{
    if (b != null && b.containsKey(cl.getName()))
    {
        return (BaseModel) b.getSerializable(cl.getName());
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7805031064669698244L;

@DatabaseField(unique=true, canBeNull=false, columnName=FIELD_ID, id=true)
@JsonProperty(required=true)
public int id;

@DatabaseField
public String name;

@DatabaseField(foreign=true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignAutoCreate=true, foreignColumnName = FIELD_ID)
public Offer offer;

public OfferCategory() 
{
}

public OfferCategory(final int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

I have no idea, why this code works fine on all Android versions, but throws exception only on Android 5.1.1 (API 22). On more recent Android versions all works fine.

Please tell me what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hrm.  Strange.  Can you post the full exception?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.j256.ormlite.field.DataPersister.getDefaultWidth()' on a null object reference at com.j256.ormlite.db.BaseDatabaseType.appendColumnArg(BaseDatabaseType.java:64)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.addCreateTableStatements(TableUtils.java:333)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:438)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:221)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:62)

Comment: If needed I may post more code or describe how to reporoduce this case

Comment: Yeah, that would be good Lumen.  This error seems to be saying that there is something wrong with how the DAO was wired.  The table information for that class is not right.

Comment: I sent you an email with a class that describes a table on which there is an exception on Android 5.1.1. Please tell me what's wrong in this class that raises an exception?

Comment: i got same issue if i use foreignColumnName annotation in my models. Any ideas how solve it?

Comment: Anyone got a solution for this? Sometimes we run into this as well although it happens on API 25 (virtual devices on Firebase Test Lab)